# Movie with a hockey player saving the world from extra terrestrials

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens

I watched it in 2015. It's in English. Possibly Hollywood movie with Russell Casse (I'm not sure).

A group of people have been abducted and a blonde girl is used for experiments. The extra terrestrials find her very hot and suddenly her nose grows simulating the penis. The main actor is a former hockey player and the weakness of the extra terrestrials is ice and ice cream.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Answer (score 3):

Could this be [Freezer Burn: The Invasion of Laxdale](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1105727/?ref_=fn_al_tt_4) (2008)?

Tom Green stars as a washed-up ice-hockey player who defends the earth against aliens in disguise.

[image: Tom Green | Crispin Glover | Freezer Burn: The Invasion of Laxdale]